# JVM - Heap size spiked but used heap decreased

Tags: java, jvm, profiling, profiler

What could be the possible reasons for this odd behavior? Or is this even odd at all?

Note: This is using Java Visual VM (from JDK7) and profiled app is a Spring Boot app in an embedded Tomcat Server.

After performing an action (currently investigating it). This happens:

[image]

Comment: As a prerequisite post the complete set of flags used to start the JVM and name the exact HotSpot version and platform.